# C# MVC, Action Method doesn't read the parameter from QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

This must be a small thing, but I am not able to figure out the issue.
I am passing 2 parameters through Querystring, but my index method receives only one of them. Not sure what could be going wrong here.

Here's my Index method

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid? empGuid = null, Guid? empPriorGuid = null)
{
// do something
}
```

And here's my URL : 
baseurl/?empGuid=7a3b9a5d-b7dd-4959-a1df-be35546d2db7&empPriorGuid=f530733e-ce8d-4bbf-8480-3551dce91337

My Index seems to receive the empPriorGuid but not the empGuid for some reason.

Comment: If you don't pass the empPriorGuid, do you get the empGuid?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Areas you need to define a route having 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

you can change route config as below :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{empGuid?}/{empPriorGuid}");
```

the "?"   in routing means optional

and call action as below :

```
@Html.Action("index", "home", new { empGuid =7a3b9a5d-b7dd-4959-a1df-be35546d2db7,empPriorGuid=7a3b9a5d-b7dd-4959-a1df-be35546d2db7})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue, it was just a strange case that something was wrong with the empGuid, when I used a different Guid it did work. Thank you all!